# Questions about specific apps are eligible?

Tags: discussion, scope

The have been a few question about the behavior of specific applications. (For example: [How to see twitter trends from the twitter app once an account has been used to login?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/586/how-to-see-twitter-trends-from-the-twitter-app-once-an-account-has-been-used-to)). We will accept this kind of question, or is it off topic?

Personally I don't have a preference on this, but maybe they can be helpful.

Related question: [What kind of "is there an app for X?" questions will we accept?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-kind-of-is-there-an-app-for-x-questions-will-we-accept)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a problem with it. The question you linked to is asking how to do something in a specific application, not "Is there an app for that?"

IMO, making questions like this off-topic is not good for the community. That would mean we can only ask questions about the OS/hardware of the phone. 3rd part applications are very much a part of the Windows Phone ecosystem, and I believe having a problem with one warrants asking a question.

My vote is leave them on topic.

Comment: Better to have a wide scope and tighten it down over the long term than to have a small scope and barely have any questions. +1

Comment: 4 upvotes plus 2 upvotes in @row1 answer. Since we don't have so much people participating I think it were decided.

Answer (score 2):

I also think that it is fine and good if they are allowed. It is certainly better than having to trawl the developers forum.

It would be a good idea to encourage users to post the version of the application in the  question/answer e.g. It is not possible to scrobble in version 1.1 of Zune. This way posts don't become useless/confusing over time.